Confused on the result of Sequence of Geometric Transformations


Here is the question. Consider the parent function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Now do the following sequence of transformations.


$1.$ Shift up by $4$ units.
$2.$ Shift left by $2$ units.
$3.$ Vertically stretch by a factor of $3$.
$4.$ Reflect about the $X$ axis.
So by these sequence of transformations, here is my answer.
After $1$ ,we get $$y=\frac{1}{x}+4$$
After $2$ ,we get $$y=\frac{1}{x+2}+4$$
After $3$, we get $$y=3\left (\frac{1}{x+2}+4 \right)$$
After $4$, we get $$y=-3\left (\frac{1}{x+2}+4 \right)$$
Is the answer correct?
My book has given the answer as $$y=\frac{-3}{x+2}+4$$

You are correct if the transformations are applied in the order stated.
If you translate up 4, the asymptote becomes $y=4$. Dilating vertically by factor 3 moves it to $y=12$. The reflection then makes it $y=-12$
Your answer has this.
The "book" answer has the asymptote at $y=4$ suggesting the dilation and reflection were done before the translation.
This is all assuming the order of transformations was specified. The way you have worded the question implies as much.
